# How to Count Items that are return by a Group By Statements

Tags: sql, ms-access

Im currently trying to create a query in SQL that groups a list of products by vendor ID and then by categoryID an returns the groups that only have more than one product listed in them.
This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT Product.VendorID, CategoryID, Count (*) as NumProducts, avg(ProductPrice) as AveragePrice
From Product, Vendor
Where ProductPrice>50
Group By Product.VendorID, CategoryID
Having Count (Product.ProductID)>1;
```

My problem is that it returns categories that also have only one item in them.

Comment: try selecting the thing you're counting to ensure that you're not actually getting more than one `ProductID` in the results

Answer (score 0):

You would seem to need a `join`.  My guess is:

```
SELECT Product.VendorID, CategoryID, Count(*) as NumProducts, avg(ProductPrice) as AveragePrice
From Product inner join
     Vendor
     on Product.VendorId = Vendor.VendorId
Where ProductPrice>50
Group By Product.VendorID, CategoryID
Having Count(*) > 1;
```

It is not clear where the columns are coming from in your query, but you may not need the `Vendor` table at all.